# Merging multiple dataframe columns with a condition

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge

I am new to pandas and I want to merge two dataframe with multiple conditions applied to it. I have master_df and trade_df.

```
master_df
Country Product
China    Apple
India    Mango
Germany  Apple
India    Mango
```

master_df['Country'] can be either export or import which we can get from trade_df

```
trade_df
Export  Import   Product
India   US         Mango
China   UK         Apple
India   Germany    Apple
```

My ultimate goal is to compare master_df['Country'] to trade_df['Export','Import'] and Product of both df and get the output as

```
master_df 
Country Product Export  Import 
China    Apple   China   UK
India    Mango   India   US
Germany  Apple   India  Germany
```

I am not sure if I am getting right as I am getting error.

```
master_df = master_df.merge(trade_df,  on =['country','Product'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say join on `['Country', 'Product']`, you tell pandas to find the two columns on both the dataframes. However, the columns for "country" on your two dataframes are different.

In your `master_df`, it is `Country`.

But in your `trade_df`, it is `Export` and `Import`.

Also, from your expectation, it can be seen that you actually want to join `master_df` twice with the `trade_df` on `Country = Export` and `Country = Import` respectively. So, you need to join them twice and concatenate them together.

What you should do (Please note that the order of the column names in the two lists must be corresponding):

```
export_df = master_df.merge(trade_df, left_on=['Country', 'Product'], right_on=['Export', 'Product']).drop_duplicates()
import_df = master_df.merge(trade_df, left_on=['Country', 'Product'], right_on=['Import', 'Product']).drop_duplicates()

df = export_df.append(import_df)
print(df)
```

This gives you the output:

```
    Country Product Export  Import
0   China   Apple   China   UK
1   India   Mango   India   US
0   Germany Apple   India   Germany
```

Comment: Your script helped well. However, I am getting duplicates if the same country is available in both export and import in trade_df.

Comment: @Lee234, You said you want to "compare" the countries and I don't actually understand how you want to compare after these joins honestly. I suggest that you may have two separate dataframes for import and export respectively. Or, you may post more sample data (cause duplicates) and expected results as a new question to see whether someone can help.

Comment: Thanks Cristopher and found the solution to delete the duplicate. The example  trade df will be trade_df = pd.DataFrame({'Export': ['India', 'China','India','China' ],
                         'Import': ['US','UK','Germany','China'],
                   'Product': ['Mango','Apple', 'Apple','Apple']}
                   ).  where China is both in export and Import. I deleted the row with multiple conditions.